# Razor can't see my closing brace

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am experiencing a very strange issue with Razor2 views. The code below is the **actual code** on which intellisense is throwing down the red squiggly, just names have been changed.

```
@model Space.ViewModels.PropertyAdminViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    ViewBag.UmbracoTitle = "Create Property";
    Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    InitView();
    AnalysePreviousState();
    SortErrorsPerStep();
    GetStepToDisplay();
}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/AdminScripts.js"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(ErrorMessage)

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("CurrentStep", StepToDisplay.ToString(), new { id="CurrentStep"})
    <input id="AddressButton" type="submit" name="@Button.AddressButton.ToString()" value="Address Details" />
    <input id="DetailsButton" type="submit" name="@Button.DetailsButton.ToString()" value="Details &amp; Description" />
    <input id="MediaButton" type="submit" name="@Button.MediaButton.ToString()" value="Images &amp; Documents" />


    switch (StepToDisplay)
    {
        case Step.Address:
            Html.RenderPartial("_AddressDetailsForm", ViewData.Model.Address);
            break;
        case Step.Details:
            Html.RenderPartial("_PropertyDetailsForm", ViewData.Model);
            break;
        case Step.Media:
            Html.RenderPartial("_MediaUploadEditForm", ViewData.Model.MediaItems);
            break;
    }


    <input id="BackButton" type="submit" name="@Button.BackButton.ToString()" value="Back" />
    <input id="NextButton" type="submit" name="@Button.NextButton.ToString()" value="Next" />
    <input id="FinishButton" type="submit" name="@Button.FinishButton.ToString()" value="Finish" />

} <-- `SQUIGGLY`


@{
    private enum Button
    {
        None,
        AddressButton,
        DetailsButton,
        MediaButton,
        NextButton,
        BackButton,
        FinishButton,
        CancelButton
    }

   public enum Step
   {
       Address,
       Details,
       Media,
       UpperBound
   }

   private const Step AddressStep = Step.Address;
   private const Step DetailsStep = Step.Details;
   private const Step MediaStep = Step.Media;
   private const Step First_Step = AddressStep;
   private const Step Last_Step = MediaStep;
   private const string CurrentStep = "CurrentStep";
   private const string DisabledAttribute = "disabled='disabled'";

   private string BackButtonState = string.Empty;
   private string NextButtonState = string.Empty;
   private string ErrorMessage = "Please correct the errors and try again.";
   private Button ButtonPressed = Button.None;
   private Step PreviousStepDisplayed = AddressStep;
   private Step StepToDisplay = AddressStep;
   private ModelStateDictionary[] StepModelState = new ModelStateDictionary[(int)Step.UpperBound];

   private void InitView()
   {
       // Create a ModelState for each individual step
        for (int key = (int)First_Step; key <= (int)Last_Step; key++)
        {
            StepModelState[key] = new ModelStateDictionary();
        }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Check form variables from the last HTTP_POST to figure where the wizard needs to be
   /// Grab the current step string along with which button was pressed
   /// </summary>
   private void AnalysePreviousState()
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[CurrentStep]))
       {
           PreviousStepDisplayed = (Step)Enum.Parse(typeof(Step), Request[CurrentStep], true);
       }

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[Button.FinishButton.ToString()]))
       {
           ButtonPressed = Button.FinishButton;
       }

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[Button.CancelButton.ToString()]))
       {
           ButtonPressed = Button.CancelButton;
       }

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[Button.NextButton.ToString()]))
       {
           ButtonPressed = Button.NextButton;
       }

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[Button.BackButton.ToString()]))
       {
           ButtonPressed = Button.BackButton;
       }

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[Button.AddressButton.ToString()]))
       {
           ButtonPressed = Button.AddressButton;
       }

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[Button.DetailsButton.ToString()]))
       {
           ButtonPressed = Button.DetailsButton;
       }

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[Button.MediaButton.ToString()]))
       {
           ButtonPressed = Button.MediaButton;
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Sort all modelstate errors into the right step
   /// </summary>
   private void SortErrorsPerStep()
   {
       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> entry in ViewData.ModelState)
       {
           foreach (int key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Step)))
           {
               //Compare the start of each error's key with the name of a step
               //if they match then that error belongs to that step
               if (entry.Key.StartsWith(((Step)key).ToString()))
               {
                   StepModelState[key].Add(entry);
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Look at the previous step to get any errors and which button was clicked
   /// and decide which step needs to be displayed now
   /// </summary>
   private void GetStepToDisplay()
   {
       //if the user tried to jump steps or finish, display the first step that has errors
       //this ensures that the wizard is completed in the intended sequence
       if (ButtonPressed != Button.NextButton && ButtonPressed != Button.BackButton)
       {
           ErrorMessage = "There are errors in the data provided. Please correct the errors and try again.";

           for (Step key = First_Step; key <= Last_Step; key++)
           {
               if (!StepModelState[(int)key].IsValid)
               {
                   DisplayStep(key, true);
                   return;
               }
           }
       }

       //if the last step has errors and the user has not hit the back button then stay on page and show the errors
       //user can go back through steps but not forward until errors are resolved
       if (!StepModelState[(int)PreviousStepDisplayed].IsValid && ButtonPressed != Button.BackButton)
       {
           DisplayStep(PreviousStepDisplayed, true);
           return;
       }

       //Otherwise move as per user request
       Step stepToDisplay = PreviousStepDisplayed;

       switch (ButtonPressed)
       {
           case Button.BackButton:
               stepToDisplay--;
               break;
           case Button.NextButton:
               stepToDisplay++;
               break;
           case Button.AddressButton:
               stepToDisplay = AddressStep;
               break;
           case Button.DetailsButton:
               stepToDisplay = DetailsStep;
               break;
           case Button.MediaButton:
               stepToDisplay = MediaStep;
               break;  
       }

       stepToDisplay = (Step)Math.Max((int)stepToDisplay, (int)First_Step);
       stepToDisplay = (Step)Math.Min((int)stepToDisplay, (int)Last_Step);

       DisplayStep(stepToDisplay, false);
   }

   private void DisplayStep(Step stepToDisplay, bool displayErrors)
   {
       StepToDisplay = stepToDisplay;
       BackButtonState = stepToDisplay == First_Step ? DisabledAttribute : string.Empty;
       NextButtonState = stepToDisplay >= Last_Step ? DisabledAttribute : string.Empty;

       //page number

       if (displayErrors)
       {
           foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> entry in StepModelState[(int)stepToDisplay])
           {
               ViewData.ModelState.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
           }
       }
   }


}
```

When I hover over Viewbag I get the usual intellisense popup, and hovering on Title explains the normal 'evaluated at runtime'.

Has anyone run into this issue? I have looked over other questions but they all had code typos or genuine mistakes. I know it's not an assembly reference issue otherwise Intellisense wouldn't know what the Viewbag is.

**UPDATE**

It looks like Intellisense is having a problem specifically dynamic assignments. Normal server code does not experience the above issue, whereas anything like Viewbag assignments or specifying the layout within @{//code here} seems broken. Also note that this only occurs on one of my .cshtml files and the others are unaffected.

**UPDATE 2**
This is the result of testing the view. Source file is the generated code file in ASP.NET temp files.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

Source Error:

Line 259:            #line default
Line 260:            #line hidden
Line 261:WriteLiteral("\r\n");
Line 262:
```

And this is the code relating to the above error in the compiled temp file:

```
WriteLiteral(" value=\"Finish\"");

WriteLiteral(" /> \r\n");


    #line 46 "F:....Create.cshtml"

} <-- see the brace!? It's right there so why does the compiler freak out?

    #line default
    #line hidden
WriteLiteral("\r\n");
```

Comment: Does the code execute?

Comment: Have you saved, closed and reopened the file?  Sometimes intellisense loses the intelli- part of its name.

Comment: try removing braces just for once and say @ViewBag.Title = "Page"; and see if it still gives that red squiggly?

Comment: @Nirman removing the braces and just giving it lines of server code prefixed with the '@' symbol works as it should, but I'd rather not have to do that for piece of server code in the view.

Comment: I actually have a massive chunk of server code below the viewbag assignments and IS has no quarrel with it. Just the first section you see above.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a side-effect of the fact that `Viewbag.Title` should be `ViewBag.Title`?

Comment: @AntP just a typo in the post sorry. This is really annoying me. Deleting the file and writing again from scratch solved nothing also!

Comment: @AutoGibbon Maybe you should post the *actual* code instead of something that is "very very close" to it as there appears to be nothing wrong with the code in your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had no idea that you can't write normal c# code into Razor views.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  You can't declare methods or classes, because the view is basically a method.  It would be like trying to declare a method or class within another method, which is not legal.  So, it is "normal" c# code, but you have to consider the context in which its running.  If you want methods, you have to change the class that the view inherits, and then do this as a separate file.

Comment: Prior to making this post, my understanding of razor view syntax was that I could write any server code provided it was declared within a @{} block. Not the case.

Comment: Useless comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
@switch (StepToDisplay)
```

It's seeing the closing switch brace as the close to your earlier one.  You may even need to enclose the switch in a razor code block `@{ switch(){} }`

As an aside, if you were using ReSharper, it would highlight the actual block of code it things it is, and you would see where Razor is thinking the end of the block would be.

EDIT:

It should look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // remove the @ from before the Html on this line
    Html.Hidden("CurrentStep", StepToDisplay.ToString(), new { id="CurrentStep"})
    // This html causes razor to switch back to "html mode"
    <input id="AddressButton" type="submit" name="@Button.Step1Button.ToString()"...

    ...

    // Add an @ here, because razor is now in Html mode
    @switch (StepToDisplay)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Back in html mode again, so we need @'s
    <input id="BackButton" type="submit" name="@Button.BackButton.ToString()"...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding the `@` before the `switch` statement yields the following result: `Unexpected "switch" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "switch" with "@".`

Comment: @AutoGibbon - The problem is that it switches back to HTML mode because of the html before it.  You shouldn't have the `@Html` on the first line after the first brace.

Comment: Doing what you suggest still causes the `unexpected "switch"...` compile error. It clearly states this is not required. On a side note - putting the generated code from temp asp.net files into the VS2012 editor shows that the generated code has and error as seen in OP.

Comment: @AutoGibbon - then the problem is something you are not showing.  This is the problem with "simplifying" the code.  Have you tried using the code you've posted here exactly and see if that works?  That should show you the problem isn't in this code.